# Android: Is there any way to listen outgoing sms?

Tags: android, sms, intercept

I know that an incoming sms can be easily intercepted using a broadcast reciever. But I did not see any way to intercept an outgoing sms. How can this be done? But there is a way to do this.. Because many third party applications read both incoming and outgoing sms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

1. **Cache all messages's** hash code on the phone
2. **Register** an [content observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) for content://sms
3. In **onChange** method of observer, enumrate all messages to check if it is in cache, if not, the message is sent out just now.

Good luck with your project :-)

**Edit: md5 method**

You can take the (arrival date + message) text to get a unique md5 output.

```
private String md5(String in) {
    MessageDigest digest;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.reset();        
        digest.update(in.getBytes());
        byte[] a = digest.digest();
        int len = a.length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
            sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Very good approach... By the way how do I store the hash codes of messages. I did not know till now, this could be possible. You help is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: You can use an md5 hash for example. Ill update my post with a Java md5 method.